# how to increase salesforce user licenses in developer edition

Tags: licenses, app-development

I am developing custom apps for salesforce using free force.com developer account. I need to create some extra users for testing purposes.
So I just wanted to ask:

1. Whether I can increase number of salesforce user licenses without changing my edition or will I have to buy partner edition?
2. if I can then how? where to buy these licenses? I don't have any checkout option in individual developer edition.

Note that I have exceeded limit for 2 users and it is showing `Contact us to obtain additional Salesforce user licenses.` But there is no link and since I am a newb, I don't know how to contact salesforce support for this. Though i know how to increase licenses in other editions.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are a Force.com ISV or Consulting Partner you can apply for a Partner Developer Edition via the partner Portal. This grants you 20 rather than 2 users.

See [Partner Development & Test Environments](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Partner_Development_&_Test_Environments)

With an individual developer edition org I believe your will need to deactivate one user so the next can be activated.

Answer (score 0):

In short it is not normal policy to increase licenses on a Dev org. You would need a sandbox attached to an enterprise+ edition org to increase licenses in a testing environment.